My tkinter canvas scrollbar is very slow because there is a lot of rectangles I need solve
Image from programm i want to fix lag problem when i move scrollbar I made alot of rectangles by tkinter canvas python and when I move scrollbar to show all rectangles it is very slow and it is very lag can someone help me ?
I tried many times but not succeeded I try alot of codes.....
from threading import Thread
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Full Window Scrolling X Y Scrollbar Example')
root.geometry("1280x1900")
main_frame = tk.Frame(root)
main_frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH,expand=1)
sec = tk.Frame(main_frame)
sec.pack(fill=tk.X,side=tk.BOTTOM)
my_canvas = tk.Canvas(main_frame,bg="white")
my_canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT,fill=tk.BOTH,expand=1)
x_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(sec,orient=tk.HORIZONTAL,command=(my_canvas.xview))
square_size = 10
for i in range(0, 1000, square_size):
    for j in range(0, 1300, square_size):
        my_canvas.create_rectangle(i, j, i + square_size, j + square_size, outline='black')
x_scrollbar.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM,fill='x')
y_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(main_frame,orient=tk.VERTICAL,command=(my_canvas.yview))
y_scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT,fill='y')
my_canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=x_scrollbar.set)
my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=y_scrollbar.set)
second_frame = tk.Frame(my_canvas)
def on_frame_configure(event):
    my_canvas.configure(scrollregion=my_canvas.bbox("all"))

main_frame.bind("<Configure>", on_frame_configure)

root.mainloop()


Had the same problem, lag with Tkinter canvas trying to handle a large number of rectangles or anything for a fact is because the canvas is trying to render all of them at once. This gives the lag in scroll, as the canvas has to update the view of all items in, which can slow it down.
Try rendering the rectangles that are currently visible within the canvas’s viewport. Use inspect tab, so instead of drawing every single rectangle upfront, focus on dynamically updating the canvas to show only those rectangles that fall within the visible area. When the user scrolls or resizes the window, you clear the canvas and redraw only the rectangles that are visible in the new viewport. Thus, fixing your problem.
Edit to @DeadCode reponse - sure, but you got to learn too so I am just giving reference codes, try and see , first replace Rectangle Creation with Line Drawing:
def draw_grid():
    my_canvas.delete("grid")
    width = my_canvas.winfo_width()
    height = my_canvas.winfo_height()
    square_size = 10
    for i in range(0, width, square_size):
        my_canvas.create_line(i, 0, i, height, fill='black', tags="grid")
    for j in range(0, height, square_size):
        my_canvas.create_line(0, j, width, j, fill='black', tags="grid")

and also you can add a function to adjust the scroll region when the canvas is resized, will have to play around to find out well
def on_frame_configure(event):
    my_canvas.configure(scrollregion=my_canvas.bbox("all"))
main_frame.bind("<Configure>", on_frame_configure)


Thank you but I want solution code please

I failed to merge the original code with your code. Can you merge the original code in the question with your code please and Thank you

No, that's YOUR job.  Do you see the philosophy here?  Instead of creating a grid by drawing 130,000 rectangles, he's drawing 230 lines.  It still produces a grid, but with much less resources.

Note that the grid lines will be shift after the canvas is scrolled.
